# Postgress select like any of array of text

Tags: database, postgresql, join, aggregate

i have 2 tables; table 1: contain a wildcard paths and table 2: files with full path;

i want to select all files that match wild card path

example:

```
table1:
| type | path |
| sys  | /etc/* |
| protected  | /etc/* |
| sys  | /sys/* |
| log  | /log/* |  

table2:
| file | path |
| f1.cmd | /etc/folder/name |
| f2.cmd | /log/folder/name |
| f3.cmd | /etc/folder/name |
| f4.cmd | /sys/folder/name |
```

**my ultimate goal is**: to create a VIEW that has all data from table2 and add one more column `type` to tell me which type does this file belongs to.
so that i can select all files that is of `type = sys` for example

** what i tried:**

step 1: get list of all paths of wanted type.

```
select array_agg(replace(path,'*','%')) from 
table1 where type = 'sys'
group by type
```

this will result with something like `{"etc\\%","sys\\%"}`

step 2 select files using `like any`

```
select * from symbols where path like any ( array['etc\\%', 'sys\\%'] )
```

this successfully returned all files with paths like one i need.

now quesiton is how can i combine both queries into one :D ?

or is there an easier way using JOIN for example.

thanks

Comment: Should `sys  | /etc/* |` be `etc  | /etc/* |`? If no, which should be the type in case the pat from table2 is `/sys/folder/name`?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the `table1.type` from each row in `table2` by checking if `table1.path` is a substring of `table2.path`:

```
with table1(type, path) as (
    values ('sys', '/etc/*'),
           ('sys', '/sys/*'),
           ('log', '/log/*'),
           ('etc', '/etc/*')
),
table2(file, path) as (
    values ('f1.cmd', '/etc/folder/name'),
           ('f2.cmd', '/log/folder/name'),
           ('f3.cmd', '/etc/folder/name'),
           ('f4.cmd', '/sys/folder/name')
)
select *,
  (select type
   from table1
   where position(replace(path, '*', '') in table2.path) > 0
   limit 1) as type
from table2;

  file  |       path       | type
--------+------------------+------
 f1.cmd | /etc/folder/name | sys
 f2.cmd | /log/folder/name | log
 f3.cmd | /etc/folder/name | sys
 f4.cmd | /sys/folder/name | sys
 (4 rows)
```

Comment: you are the man <3. thanks just one problem; a type can exsists in mutliple types; (same path in table1 can be categories under different name).

only query i will be running is getting all files of type X;

Comment: nice, can you exemplify somehow? I'm not really sure I got the idea @Zalaboza